# I am unable to call method Saveaimage if image size above 80kb

Tags: c#, ajax

`[WebMethod]
public static string Saveaimage(string dataimg)
{
dataimg = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBABgDH//2Q==";

```
var base64Data = Regex.Match(dataimg, @"data:image/(?<type>.+?),(?<data>.+)").Groups["data"].Value;
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);

        File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("/abcd.png"), bytes);

        return "OK";
    }`
```

Comment: Ajax call method giving me error (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error))

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include more information

Comment: What maximum size request is the server set to accept?

Comment: almost 2mb to 5mb image data

Comment: What is the error? You need to include more info.

Comment: Ajax call method giving me error (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error))

Answer (score 0):

Using hidden field i have solved this no need to ajax to tranfer Image data